# Nginx as LDAP forward proxy. How?

Tags: nginx, ldap

I need a forward TCP proxy for LDAP-service **db.debian.org:389**. This is public LDAP. I use Nginx for it.

Here is the Nginx config:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen     389;
        proxy_pass db.debian.org:389;
    }
}
```

Nginx opens TCP port port 389 on localhost

```bash
nc -zv localhost 389

Connection to localhost (127.0.0.1) 389 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

However LDAP-service does not work on localhost:389

```bash
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost -x -b 'gid=slyon,ou=users,dc=debian,dc=org' -v -d8

ldap_initialize( ldap://localhost:389/??base )
ber_get_next failed, errno=0.
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Why? How to proxy LDAP requests?

Comment: Is that your *entire* nginx configuration? By itself that should cause nginx to fail (with `no "events" section in configuration`). If I fix that error, your config seems to work just fine; I'm able to interact with `db.debian.org` at `ldap://localhost`.

Comment: Yes that was correct. A part of nginx configuration is "hidden" in nginx.conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole Nginx configuration must have sections: `http{}`, `stream{}` and `events{}` at the same level.

File `nginx.conf` must be in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

It should look like (this is unpriveleged Nginx)

```yaml
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /tmp/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;
    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '{"time": "$time_iso8601",...}';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       8080;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html;
        }
    }
}

stream {
    log_format  upstream_log  '{"time": "$time_iso8601",...}';

    server {
        listen     389;
        proxy_pass db.debian.org:389;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstream_log;
    }
}
```